# Control on embedded form not refreshing (Delphi, Firemonkey)

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, rad-studio

I have a very simple Firemonkey project (RadStudio 10.3.3) that I am building to test certain layout options for a future project.  In the past with VCL, I used modal forms.  The project I am testing uses panels (Panel1 and Panel2) on the main form (Form1) to embed two additional forms (Form2 and Form3).  The two embedded forms consist of a single listbox (ListBox1) on each form.  The panels on the main form overlay, so I use the Visibility property to show the embedded form that I want.  All the code is on the main form.

The issue I have is that when I switch between Form2 and Form3, the strings loaded into the listbox on Form3 never appear.  I have tried Repaint on the listbox and panel, InvalidateRect on the listbox, SetFocus on the panel, etc., all followed by Application.ProcessMessages.  Nothing works successfully.

The main code is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure EmbedForm(AParent:TControl; AForm:TCustomForm);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses Unit2, Unit3;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Embed Form2 in Panel1
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  EmbedForm(Panel1, Form2);
  Panel1.Visible := true;

  // Embed Form3 in Panel2
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  EmbedForm(Panel2, Form3);
  Panel2.Visible := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Populate ListBox1 on Form2 - the LOAD button
  Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add('Hello');
  Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add('World');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Hide Panel1 (Form2) and show Panel2 (Form3)
  Panel1.Visible := false;
  Panel2.Visible := true;
  // Populate ListBox1 on Form3
  Form3.ListBox1.Items.Add('Goodbye');
  Form3.ListBox1.Items.Add('World');
  // Repaint (Here's why I have tried various things to get the listbox strings to show up)
  //Panel2.Repaint;
  //Form3.ListBox1.Repaint;
  //Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

procedure TForm1.EmbedForm(AParent: TControl; AForm: TCustomForm);
begin
  while AForm.ChildrenCount>0 do
    AForm.Children[0].Parent:=AParent;
end;

end.
```

Form2 is as follows:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ListBox;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

Form3 is as follows:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.ListBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

The .fmx files are below, as requested.

Unit1.fmx (Form1):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 232.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 448.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Load'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Position.X = 328.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 448.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Next'
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 393.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Position.Y = 43.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 393.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
  end
end
```

Unit2.fmx (Form2):

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    Align = Center
    TabOrder = 0
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    Viewport.Width = 200.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 200.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Unit3.fmx (Form3):

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListBox1: TListBox
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 1
    DisableFocusEffect = True
    DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
    DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
    Viewport.Width = 196.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 196.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

Again, Form2 and Form3 each only contain a listbox (Listbox1 on both) and no additional code.  I simply run the executable, click Button1 to display Hello World, then click Button2 to switch panels and display the second form and its listbox.  As I am new to Firemonkey, I am sure I am missing something simple.  Thanks for any and all help!

---

The solution was very simple.  I had to remove the CreateForm events for Form2 and Form3 from the project's initialization settings--a dumb mistake on my part.  It was losing the reference to those forms during execution.

Comment: FWIW, it's much easier to put the embedded content inside of a `TLayout` on the source form, then just assign the parent of that layout.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for the information.  I will begin looking into the TLayout container.  I used a TPanel because I was familiar with them in VCL.

Comment: I deleted my answer for now, as you claim it can't be the case. However, since the child parent relations can not be seen from the code you have posted, I ask you to add the three `.fmx` files to your question. I also need to emphasize, that I cannot reproduce your problem if the panels are direct childs of `Form1`. It just works the way you intended.

Comment: @Tom - I have done as you've requested.  As you can see, there is nothing involved with Unit2 (Form2) or Unit3 (Form3).  Since you can't duplicate the problem, I will just build another test case from scratch and see if the problem exists.  I have my main piece of software that also has this issue, which is why I built the simple test code to verify my issue.  As I mentioned, I just updated to RadStudio 10.3.3, though I had the same issue in 10.3.2.  Thank you for all your assistance!

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, now you have, in `Unit1.fmx` a `TPanel` and as a child to that panel, a `TLayout`, which you don't have in `Unit1.pas`. Otoh, you don't have `Panel2` at all in `Unit1.fmx`! So `Unit1.fmx` doesn't match `Unit1.pas`. If you have changed the second panel to a `TLayout` (based on Jerry's suggestion), and that panel was in the place of the current layout, then that is exactly what I said in my answer. That `Panel2` was a child of `Panel1` and not a child of `Form1`. Which gives exactly the behaviour you described. Do you agree?

Comment: Did you verify that the code you now have posted actually exhibits the error you claim it does? I have a feeling this is just a waste of time!

Comment: @Tom - Yes, this is the code, and it still fails.  The application starts and displays Form2 in Panel1 correctly (the listbox is empty).  Clicking Button1 then populates the listbox with the strings "Hello" and "World" correctly.  Then, Clicking Button2 displays Form3 in Panel2 correctly, but the listbox is empty.  It never shows "Goodbye" and "World".  I have tried Repaint, etc., as I noted above.  Both my development and test applications (posted above) exhibit this behavior.

I do apologize for posting the incorrect .fmx file earlier.  That was completely my fault.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I am compiling Windows 32-bit.  I also tried Windows 64-bit and saw the same behavior.  For whatever reason (likely me missing something simple), the listbox on Form3 will not display its contents.

Comment: Well, as I thought, just a waste of time. The code you have shown **does not exhibit the problem**. And there is nothing in the present code that even could, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: @Tom Sorry for your frustration, Tom.  However, your frustration caused me to dig into the .fmx files and eventually locate the problem!  Thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: I have posted it below.  The error was in the application initialization, where I had left in the references to create Form2 and Form3.  Then, when I created duplicates of the forms in the code, the references were lost and it never updated the listboxes.  Thank you again!  You forced me to look deeply into the .fmx files, which is something I had never done before.  I truly appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can reproduce the error is by setting the parent - child relation between the form and the two panels wrong.

E.g. I can reproduce the erroneous behaviour you describe, if `Panel2` is a child of `Panel1`, but if they are both childs of the form, I can not reproduce the problem. Perhaps you dropped the second panel on `Panel1` by mistake? Check the structure window in the IDE.

---

**Edit** after `.fmx` files were added to the question

Looking at the supplied `Unit1.fmx` which ends like this:

```
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Align = Center
    Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 393.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object Layout1: TLayout
      Align = Contents
      Size.Width = 640.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 393.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
```

There is no `Panel2` as there should be according to `Unit1.pas`. Instead there is a `Layout1` as child to `Panel1`. So, the now posted `.fmx` file doesn't match the `.pas` file you supplied yesterday. But it might still confirm what I already said.

If `Panel2` has been substituted with this layout, and in other words `Panel2` was a child to `Panel1`, then this would exactly explain the behaviour you asked about originally.

Comment: I will check that in the morning and let you know!  Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: I just looked into my test code (posted above), and both panels are children of Form1.  Sorry, I forgot that I had uploaded the test code into my CM software.  Thank you again for the suggestion!

Comment: My apologies, Tom!  I had started playing around with TLayout, per Jerry's comment, and accidentally posted the working code vice the original code.  I am very sorry!  I have updated the .fmx code above to reflect the original two-panel design!  Again, I apologize!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to Tom's frustration (again, I am sorry Tom!) and my own, I rebuilt the test application once again.  This time, neither listbox would show the strings.  I then began thinking about Form2 and Form3 losing their connection to Form1, so I looked into the .fmx files that Tom had asked about.  That led me to looking into the Project initialization file, and voila!

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form3};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  //Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);  <-- NOW COMMENTED OUT
  //Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);  <-- NOW COMMENTED OUT
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The application was creating Form2 and Form2 on startup, and then I would create duplicates within the code, thus leading to a loss of reference.  I simply commented out the Form2 and Form3 lines in startup to keep the application from creating them and it works as intended.  Thanks, Tom!

Comment: Well, that certainly explains the problem partly, but since `Form2` actually worked as intended, you must have outcommented the first of those lines already earlier. Mysterious are the ways of bugs ;)

Comment: Yes, I had commented it out last month when I initially started working on this test application.  A few days ago, when I added Form3, I completely forgot to comment it out.  You are absolutely right, mysterious are the ways of bugs!  Tom, I truly thank you for all your help here!